# Integration in Fourier transform

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, fourier-transform

Can someone help me how to integrate the following integration?
$$
F(\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-j\omega t}\frac{Q}{(4\pi Dt)^{3/2}}\,e^{-\large\frac{\gamma^2}{4Dt}}\,\mathrm{d}t
$$
[original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WSUl.jpg)

Comment: Show some effort: [learn how to type it out here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Is everything in that real?

Comment: Except for the complex exponential, everything is real @Gaffney

Comment: I didnt mean to offend anyone, I joined this community just now, so I didnt know how to do it @MikePierce

Comment: I have edited your question. Please make sure I got it right.

Comment: @robjohn Its perfect

Comment: Then there is a problem since $t^{3/2}$ is imaginary when $t\lt0$, and the exponential is not integrable near $0^-$.

Comment: @robjohn so there is no solution to this integral?

Comment: @AnkitSahay Have you tried contour integration?

Comment: @Troy No I havent
I dont know how to do it

Comment: @AnkitSahay is D positive?

Comment: @troy no such information was given to me. So probably we can assume so.

Comment: @AnkitSahay: not the way its written